# What is the initial state in the second register in Shor's algorithm?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, shors-algorithm

Following up on [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14702/shors-algorithm-initialization-of-second-register) question, can someone help me clear up the notation we're using for states in Shor's algorithm? It's very unclear what the sentence "where the second register is $|1\rangle$  made from $n$ qubits" in the Wikipedia article means. The input state is supposedly $|0\rangle^{\otimes 2n+1} \otimes |1\rangle$. The first register makes sense, and one could write $|0\rangle^{\otimes 2n+1}=|\underbrace{0 \ldots 0}_{2n+1}\rangle$. Would one say that's $|0\rangle$ made from $2n+1$ qubits?

It appears we have states for all integers $0 \le k < 2^n$, which makes sense because if our fundamental qubit states are $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ then we can write $k$ in binary and we have $2^n$ tensor product states. Isn't the state $|0\rangle = |\underbrace{0 \ldots 0}_{n}\rangle$ and $|1\rangle = |1\underbrace{0 \ldots 0}_{n-1}\rangle$?

Clearly there must be $n$ qubits in the second register as input since $U$ (multiplication by $a$ modulo $N$) is a $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix. Yes, $U$ has eigenvectors, and $|1\rangle$ is an equal sum of those eigenvectors, but that doesn't help me understand the fixed input state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean that the second register uses $n$ qubits, and it's in the state $|1\rangle$.

This is using the standard way of enumerating the $2^n$ possible (computational basis) $n$-qubit states, so $|k\rangle$ denotes the $n$-qubit state corresponding to the binary string which in base-10 corresponds to $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Consider for example $n=2$. Then
$$|0\rangle \simeq|0,0\rangle,
\quad
|1\rangle \simeq|0,1\rangle,
\quad
|2\rangle \simeq|1,0\rangle,
\quad
|3\rangle \simeq|1,1\rangle.$$
So more generally, you could say that $|1\rangle$ denotes the $n$-qubit state with binary representation $|0\rangle^{\otimes(n-1)}\otimes|1\rangle$. Although this expression is generally not very insightful in this context.

Note also that conventions may vary, and so you might have the equivalence $|1\rangle\simeq|1\rangle\otimes|0\rangle^{\otimes(n-1)}$ rather than the one above. This doesn't affect any result of course, it's only a notational detail.

The reason you use this particular state for the second register is that, as you might observe directly, the modular multiplication operator $U_a$ has eigenvectors $|u_s\rangle$, corresponding to eigenvalues $e^{2\pi i s/p}$ with $p$ period, which sum to precisely $|1\rangle$. Therefore using $|1\rangle$ as second register is a convenient way to perform a quantum phase estimation with a set of possible eigenstates of $U_a$ in superposition.

Comment: Okay cool, I think we’re saying more or less the same thing. Thanks, this clears up my confusion.

Comment: I am a little bit unsure about you answer. In Shor algorithm we have $n$ qubits initialized to state $|0\rangle$ used for saving a period and $m$ qubits initialized to state $|1\rangle$ to which result of a modular exponential is saved. If I understand your answer correctly, it should always hold $m=1$? On Wiki I see that the second register is multi-qubit, not only one quantum bit. What am I missing?

Comment: @MartinVesely I agree that the second $m$-qubit register starts on the state $|1\rangle$; but I'd disagree that the $m$ qubits are initialized in the state $|1\rangle$. These are very different statements. For period finding we want the former, because we need a state that is a balanced sum of (some of) the eigenstates of $U_a$. You can also see it in the Wikipedia page when they compute the sum of the $|\psi_k\rangle$ and get $|1\rangle$. There you don't get $|1\rangle\equiv |1\rangle^{\otimes m}$, you get the $m$-qubit state corresponding to the binary decomposition of $1\in{\Bbb Z}$.

Comment: @glS: Thanks for explanation. Notation could be sometimes tricky.

Comment: @glS I really think $|1\rangle = |1\rangle \otimes |0\rangle^{\otimes (n-1)}$ is so much clearer. We're distinguishing between $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $1 \in \{0,1\}$, integer and binary 1. When I actually built the circuit in Qiskit, you see clearly that you initialize the second register to all $|0\rangle$'s and put an $X$ gate only on the first bit, which flips it to a 1.